# Why does Entity Framework allow me to insert into a table with an identity primary key on the first iteration of a loop but fails after?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm using the following code to insert records into a table:

```
        foreach (string tag in splitTags)
        {
            objTag.Tag = tag;
            objTag.ReportId = objReport.ReportId;
            objTag.TagId = 0;
            context.Tags.Add(objTag);
            context.SaveChanges();
        }
```

The table has a primary key `TagID` which is an identity column.

It works as expected on the first iteration of the loop but fails on any other attempt giving an error:

> Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'Tags' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF"

I want to know why this is happening even though TagID is set to 0 before any context add or save changes takes place, `ReportID` is also the same each time, the only difference is the Tag text.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no object creation in your loop
You insert the same object again and again.

Actually you change the Primary key of an existing object, and this is just not allowed.

So create a new object in each loop !

In general, SaveChanges after such a loop should be prefered.

Comment: Brilliant, worked perfectly thanks. I'll accept your answer as soon as it lets me!

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @Holger's answer, you can rid of `foreach` like this:

```cs
var tags = splitTags.Select(s => new Tag { Tag = s, ReportId = reportId });
context.Tags.AddRange(tags);
context.SaveChanges();
```